# Собеседование по java

Tags: java

У меня на днях произойдет важное событие, мое первое собеседование по java se junior

Хотелось бы услышать примерно список вопросов, возможно какие то хитрые вопросы, которые ставят джуниора в ступор( ну и ответы, если не сложно(= )

Я знаю что в интернете полно всего этого, вроде много прочитал, много выучил и все одно меня немного "трясёт"

Заранее благодарен

Comment: Все там были, никто не умер - не ссы :)

Comment: Поспрашивают про коллекции, про потоки, может быть. Какие методы есть у `Object`. Чем чекнутые исключения от нечекнутых отличаются. Про особенности наследования (порядок вызова конструкторов, расширение и сужение типов). Спросят, слышал ли что-нибудь о сборщике мусора и какие типы ссылок бывают (в суровом случае). Как-то так )

Comment: @zamutil посмотрите мой ответ на [этот вопрос](http://hashcode.ru/questions/260345/%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%89%D1%8C-%D0%B2-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B5-%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82-%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B5%D1%80) - тема вся та же, ответ такой же...

Comment: @Barmaley  
классный первый комент)
я так понял, пока не попробуешь, не успокоишься

Comment: Про модификаторы доступа еще могут спросить и про виртуальные методы.

Comment: а что такое виртуальные методы в java ?

Comment: @argamidon в Java все методы (кроме статических) виртуальные :) В этом одно из коренных отличий Java от плюсов

Comment: я хотел сказать что, прочитав несколько книжек по яве, ни в одной я не встретил это слово "виртуальный метод". Может быть виртуальные методы и существуют, но во всленной ява ИМХО упоминать не нужно.

Comment: @argamidon это такой вопрос с подвохом. Если человек рубит в ООП то ответ знает, а если не совсем то не знает :)

Comment: @argamidon тем не менее меня на собеседовании спрашивали. И лучше говорить джава :3

Comment: ну зачем знать технологии/понятия/аббривиатуры/термины из других зыков? Я слышал что с++ мешает познать java, особенно если человек новичок. Я специально не изучал с++, а сразу сел за java. И не знаю что такое виртуальный метод. И не понимаю зачем знать чтото из с++. Если на то пошло давайте уже из паскаля/пхп/питона  что нибудь спросим :)
зы хорошо буду джава говорить ато интервьюер проснется не с той ноги... XD

Comment: @argamidon ну не надо быть таким категоричным. То, что вы не изучали с++ это скорее минус чем плюс. И в общем полезно знать как другие языки работают и вообще компутер в целом. Регистры там, команды низкоуровневые. Спросят вас про производительность какой-нибудь каверзный вопрос и всё. Ведь если человек учится на стоматолога, например, то не зря ему надо учить все строение тела человека. Точно также и программист. Все взаимосвязано.

Comment: > ну зачем знать технологии/понятия/аббривиатуры/термины из других зыков? Я слышал что с++ мешает познать java, особенно если человек новичок. Я специально не изучал с++, а сразу сел за java. И не знаю что такое виртуальный метод. И не понимаю зачем знать чтото из с++

Предмет для гордости не ахти. "Виртуальный метод" это не "чтото из с++", а общепринятый термин из области объектно-ориентированного программирования, не привязанный к конкретному языку, такой же как, например "позднее связывание".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Пожалуйста, просмотрите ссылки, которые добавлены у меня в избранное. (Скоро сам пойду на собеседование, наверное).

1. [Многопоточность в Java](http://habrahabr.ru/post/164487/)
2. [Java собеседование. Коллекции](http://habrahabr.ru/post/162017/)
3. [Примеры с собеседований по Java на quizful](http://www.quizful.net/test)
4. [Garbage Collection наглядно](http://habrahabr.ru/post/112676/)
5. [Несколько интересных вопросов с реальных собеседований](http://javatalks.ru/topics/41222)
6. [Записки трезвого практика](http://www.skipy.ru/)

Будет отлично, если еще кто-то отпишется по теме.

Comment: @argamidon, пожалуйста, оформляйте ответы согласно правилам сообщества, иначе они будут удаляться.

Answer (score 2):

Излагаю наиболее чзв, на собеседованиях, которые посещал: Про паттерны спросят, про то какие книги читал по джаве. Про фреймворки которые знаешь.Само собой примеры кода. Про бд спросят ( MySql, SQLite, Oracle). А про Spring слышали чтонибудь? А Hibernate? Еще вспомни про отличие классов от интерфейсов. Ну и по одному примеру, устному, для каждого принципа ООП. Про системы контроля версий?  Примерно так.

Answer (score 0):

Совсем не полный список, но хорошая сборная солянка. Процентов 80 покрывает.
[327 вопроса на собеседование Java Developer](http://becomejavasenior.com/blog/2015/07/01/327-interview-questions-java-developer/)

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Поясните, на чем основано ваше утверждение? Добавьте в ответ минимальный необходимый пример решения (информацию по ссылке могут удалить и ответ потеряет ценность).